# Is it possible to update multiple documents with different values using mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

These are two documents for example.

```
{
    "_id" : ("61caeebb9103bcd216110f52"),
    "name" : "Anshul",
    "age" : 23.0,
    "email" : "anshulsharma4445@gmail.com"
},
{
    "_id" : ("61caeed69103bcd216110f66"),
    "name" : "Anshul"
    "age" : 25,
    "email" : "aastik4445@gmail.com"
}
```

is it possible to update name of both the documents with different values with a single query. This is just for reference in real there are lot of documents.

Comment: Its not possible

Comment: Can we use aggregate ?

Comment: No, aggregate is used to fetch data. not update it